# Spring Boot 3 webflux is not compatible with springdoc openapi 2

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I add bellow codes in my build.gradle:

```
...
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:3.0.2'
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui', version: '2.0.2'
...
```

I tried by add:
`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'`
but not working too
and when I have spring boot web with following dependency everything worked for me:
`implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: my problem resolved. I made a mistake and had custom swagger-ui and I don't mention it. This configuration worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Spring Boot 3, we need to use the OpenAPI Doc v2 https://springdoc.org/v2/.

1. WebMVC - add dependency to
   implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.3'
2. WebFlux - add dependency to
   implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.0.3'

Swagger UI Path will be  at http://:/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: Have you managed to change the webjars path to another one ?